# Is there a dog in Rembrandt's "The Night Watch"?

Tags: art

This, of course, is Rembrandt's *The Night Watch*

[image: The Night Watch]

In the bottom right, I swear there's a figure of a dog or something, but I can't see anything about there being a dog in the painting.

Does anybody know what it actually is?

Comment: It does seem to be a dog. [This analysis](https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/renaissance-reformation/baroque-art1/holland/a/rembrandt-the-night-watch) of the painting, by Dr. Wendy Schaller, describes "_In the left foreground, a young boy carrying a powder horn dashes off to collect more powder for the musketeers. Opposite him, a drummer taps out a cadence while a dog barks enthusiastically at his feet._"

Comment: Surprised no historian has mentioned how Rembrandt got a time-travelling young John Prine to model for the guy in white!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dog. Not only a good scan like that in https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/en/collection/SK-C-5 shows it is a dog, but sources like https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/curators-discover-hidden-sketch-in-rembrandts-night-watch-180979196/ mention it: "New research also indicates that a dog at the bottom of the composition has faded over the centuries".

Comment: A Netherlands-based history account I follow was [just saying earlier this week](https://twitter.com/fakehistoryhunt/status/1718365274087252394) how Dutch "masters" paintings tend to contain background dogs.